# Do you know an easy to install javascript chat?

Tags: javascript, chat

I have tried AjaxIm but it has no activity since a long time and it's a bit buggy.
I am searching for something with a facebook like look an feel.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use holla.

You can create channels, invite friends to those channels, chat and share files.

https://github.com/maccman/holla

Comment: Thks for the answer but it's not enough facebook like, it's much more in the IRC feeling.